# Char template type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, character

Can anyone explain me why I can use the Char as a template type parameter such as:

```
template <class Char>
```

I didn't find any reference of this class.

Answer (score 4):

The token `Char` is just an identifier without any prior meaning. It names the first template argument. You could have written equivalently,

```
template <class IKnowCeePlusPlus>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Char` means nothing in C++ land. It's an indentifier just like any other and this is basically the same as if you wrote `template <class T>` or `template <typename T>`.